# What is the displs argument in MPI_Scatterv?

Tags: c++, c, mpi, scatterview

The `displs` argument from `MPI_Scatterv()` function is said to be an "integer array (of length group size). Entry *i* specifies the displacement (relative to sendbuf from which to take the outgoing data to process i".
Let's say then that I have `sendcounts` argument

```
int sendcounts[7] = {3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4};
```

The way I'm reasoning this out is that the `displs` array should always start with value of 0 since the first entry's displacement is 0 relative to `sendbuf`, so in my example above, `displs` should look like:

```
int displs[7] = {0, 3, 6, 9, 13, 17, 21};
```

Is that correct? I know this is a trivial question, but for some reason the web does not help at all. There are no good examples out there, hence my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, displacements gives the root information the information as to which items to send to a particular task - the offset of the starting item.  So in most simple cases (e.g., you'd use `MPI_Scatter` but the counts don't evenly divide) this can be immediately calculated from counts information:

```
displs[0] = 0;              // offsets into the global array
for (size_t i=1; i<comsize; i++)
    displs[i] = displs[i-1] + counts[i-1];
```

But it doesn't need to be that way; the only restriction is that the data you're sending can't overlap.  You could count from the back just as well:

```
displs[0] = globalsize - counts[0];                 
for (size_t i=1; i<comsize; i++)
    displs[i] = displs[i-1] - counts[i];
```

or any arbitrary order would work as well.

And in general the calculations can be more complicated because the types of the send buffer and receive buffers have to be *consistent* but not necessarily the same - you often get this if you're sending multidimensional array slices, for instance.

As an example of the simple cases, the below does the forward and backward cases:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    const int root = 0;             // the processor with the initial global data

    size_t globalsize;
    std::vector<char> global;       // only root has this

    const size_t localsize = 2;     // most ranks will have 2 items; one will have localsize+1
    char local[localsize+2];        // everyone has this
    int  mynum;                     // how many items 

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); 

    int comrank, comsize;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comrank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comsize);

    // initialize global vector
    if (comrank == root) {
        globalsize = comsize*localsize + 1;
        for (size_t i=0; i<globalsize; i++) 
            global.push_back('a'+i);
    }

    // initialize local
    for (size_t i=0; i<localsize+1; i++) 
        local[i] = '-';
    local[localsize+1] = '\0';

    int counts[comsize];        // how many pieces of data everyone has
    for (size_t i=0; i<comsize; i++)
        counts[i] = localsize;
    counts[comsize-1]++;

    mynum = counts[comrank];
    int displs[comsize];

    if (comrank == 0) 
        std::cout << "In forward order" << std::endl;

    displs[0] = 0;              // offsets into the global array
    for (size_t i=1; i<comsize; i++)
        displs[i] = displs[i-1] + counts[i-1];

    MPI_Scatterv(global.data(), counts, displs, MPI_CHAR, // For root: proc i gets counts[i] MPI_CHARAs from displs[i] 
                 local, mynum, MPI_CHAR,                  // I'm receiving mynum MPI_CHARs into local */
                 root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);                   // Task (root, MPI_COMM_WORLD) is the root

    local[mynum] = '\0';
    std::cout << comrank << " " << local << std::endl;

    std::cout.flush();
    if (comrank == 0) 
        std::cout << "In reverse order" << std::endl;

    displs[0] = globalsize - counts[0];                 
    for (size_t i=1; i<comsize; i++)
        displs[i] = displs[i-1] - counts[i];

    MPI_Scatterv(global.data(), counts, displs, MPI_CHAR, // For root: proc i gets counts[i] MPI_CHARAs from displs[i] 
                 local, mynum, MPI_CHAR,                  // I'm receiving mynum MPI_CHARs into local */
                 root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);                   // Task (root, MPI_COMM_WORLD) is the root

    local[mynum] = '\0';
    std::cout << comrank << " " << local << std::endl;

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Running gives:

```
In forward order
0 ab
1 cd
2 ef
3 ghi

In reverse order
0 hi
1 fg
2 de
3 abc
```

Comment: I am noticing that you are inputting values in `global` from the Root rank. after doing that won't you need to Broadcast `global` to all ranks? I am thinking this way because if `global` is then being used in `Scatterv` don't all ranks need to know the data inside `global`?

Comment: The proper term for the matching datatypes is *congruent*. Consistent sounds strange to me, but then, I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: @user7331538, the first four arguments of `MPI_Scatterv` are only used by the root rank. The rest of the ranks receive the chunks in their receive buffers and they need not have access to the data in `global` (it comes from the root).

Comment: oh yes of course that makes senes. Thanks a lot! I posted a related question about scatter problem a few days ago and i would really like some help and review on it. if you have the time I would appreciate if you can take a look @HristoIliev. here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41317672/data-changes-after-passing-from-mpi-scatter

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your reasoning is correct - for **contiguous** data. The point of the `displacements` parameter in `MPI_Scatterv` is to also allow **strided** data, meaning that there are unused gaps of memory in the `sendbuf` between the chunks.

Here is an [example for contigous data](https://gist.github.com/ehamberg/1263868). The official documentation actually contains good [examples for strided data](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report/node106.htm#Node106).